# Регулярное выражение - получение текста из середины строки

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Помогите пожалуйста написать регулярное выражение, строка:

`"Фамилия</td><td>ВОТ ЭТО НАДО ВЫТАЩИТЬ</td>"`

нужно вытащить из строки текст `"ВОТ ЭТО НАДО ВЫТАЩИТЬ"`

При этом части `"Фамилия</td><td>"` и `"</td>"` во всех строчках постоянны!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match_all('~Фамилия</td><td>(.*?)</td>~u', $text, $matches); // обратите внимание на ~u
```

либо:

```
preg_match_all('~<td>(.*?)</td>~u', $text, $matches); // обратите внимание на ~u
```

Comment: А что означает ~u?

Comment: Вы с такой уверенностью написали регулярки с модификатором utf-8, что мне аж интересно стало, откуда вы знаете, что ТС будет работать не с cp1251?<br> Так что я бы не был так уверен по поводу <b>u</b>

Comment: Практика :)
Обычно если люди приводят вполне рабочее регулярное выражение и имеют с ним проблемы - то в 90% случаев проблема как раз в ~u, но при этом и сам текст регулярного выражения должен быть в utf-8

Answer (score 1):

```
/Фамилия<\/td><td>([\W]+)<\/td>/
```

Comment: А как вытащить ТОЛЬКО содержимое?
без "Фамилия</td><td>" и "</td>

Comment: Убрать из регулярки слово <b>Фамилия</b> xD<br>
вообще в коде просто пишете типа <br>
<pre><code>
    preg_match_all($preg, $match, $matches);
    //смотрим массив matches и находим там то что нужно...
</code></pre><br>
Еще как вариант `preg_replace($preg, '$1', $str)`... Тут мы заменяем старую строку на искомые значения, хотя, как мне показалось, вам нужен именно первый вариант...

Comment: AlexWindHope, отличная шутка)
и без td /td (просто теги затерлись при комментировании)

Comment: ОМГ зачем?О_о